# java regex - matching part of string stored in variable

Tags: java, regex, variables

I need to extract up to the directory a file is in, in the folder path. To do so, I created a simple regex. Here is an example path `\\myvdi\Prod\2014\10\LTCG\LTCG_v2306_03_07_2014_1226.pfd`

The regex below will find exactly what I need, but my problem is storing it into a variable. This is what I have below.  It fails at the string array

```
  String[] temp = targetFile.split("\\.*\\");
  folder = temp[0];
```

Suggestions?

Thanks!

**Edit**
The exception being thrown is: `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 4`

Comment: `It fails at the string array` How does it fail? What errors you see?

Comment: Also what output/result you ware expecting?

Comment: I am expecting this as an output: \\myvdi\Prod\2014\10\LTCG\

Comment: As to what errors I see, an exception is thrown.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add stacktrace of thrown exception there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you need:

```
String path = "\\myvdi\\Prod\\2014\\10\\LTCG\\LTCG_v2306_03_07_2014_1226.pfd";
String dir = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Comment: what does msg refer to?

Comment: Sorry i meant your path String.

Answer (score 2):

**If your path is valid** within your file system, I would recommend not using regex and using a `File` object instead:

```
String path = "\\myvdi\\Prod\\2014\\10\\LTCG\\LTCG_v2306_03_07_2014_1226.pfd";
File file = new File(path);
System.out.println(file.getParent());
```

**Output**

```
\\myvdi\\Prod\\2014\\10\\LTCG\\
```

Comment: what are the advantages of this one?

Comment: Amongst the advantages, you are using the appropriate API objects and methods, with means to validate and control the actual object pointed at, which is a `File`. Also you can validate whether it exists or not, is accessible or not, etc. etc.

Comment: Even though I select another's answer to be what I was looking for (a direct answer to my question), I will be using this in another place in my code. So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Pattern & Matchers which are much more powerful; from your description I'm not sure if you want to get the whole folder path, but if it is, here is a solution:

```
String s = "\\\\myvdi\\Prod\\2014\\10\\LTCG\\LTCG_v2306_03_07_2014_1226.pfd";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\\\+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\\\+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\\\+)+).+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.matches()){

  System.out.println(m.group(m.groupCount()-1));
}
```